# Clear command for discord.py bot (with cogs) not working

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I keep getting these errors whenever i run my code
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWWIC.png)

Here's the code:
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGaQI.png)
Btw the bit off screen is just "inline = False"

Btw im using this inside a cog for my discord.py bot

Comment: Im new to using cogs so im not sure whats wrong here and how to fix it

Comment: Please provide code in text form. Please also provide the full stack trace or error log

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I forgot to add `self` to

```
async def clear(self, ctx, amount : int):
```